# Slick Grid Column Selector

Tags: slickgrid

Just make sure i'm not reinventing something..

I would like to have a column selector dialog that allows the user to select which columns are shown/hidden. Has anyone done a dialog that working with slickgrid?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [example4-model](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html) in the SlickGrid download package shows an easy way to implement this. Using this code worked fine for me.

Comment: I looked again at the sample and it does work in there using the ColumnPicker. If you right click the column header i see what i was looking for. Sorry, I didn't know i had to right click there to find it....